# How to put Cubejs Playground behind Authentication

Tags: cube.js

In my non-prod environment of cubejs, we have playground running and we see that playground runs without any authentication. I want to have Playground behind auth.

I went through cubejs doc and it looks like we can add auth for APIs(SQL, GRAPHQL, REST APIs) but there seems no way to add auth for Playground. Is there a way to do that because we don't want to expose data even for non-prod envs?
JWT token auth for APIs - https://cube.dev/docs/product/auth